# Ubuntu goes down daily at night - VM

Tags: networking, virtualization, hyper-v

We have a Ubuntu VM on Hyper-V and on it we have a LAMP server installed and an internal domain accessible from the intranet .

Everyday we have to restart it because the connectivity to the server goes down .

When we log to the VM , the network is down , no internet at all

I saw the logs and something happen at 2am

Here is more info :

> Linux hpjs-desktop 2.6.32-38-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 4 11:13:04
>   UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/network/interfaces

> auto lo iface lo inet loopback
>
> auto seth0 iface seth0 inet dhcp

cat /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf

> option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned
>   integer 8;
>
> send host-name "";
>
> request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
>           domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
>           netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
>           rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

ifconfig

> eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:5d:01:05:16
>
> ```
>       inet addr:192.168.1.103  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0 
>
>       inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe01:516/64 Scope:Link
>
>       UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>
>       RX packets:245080 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>
>       TX packets:26105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>
>       RX bytes:30436098 (30.4 MB)  TX bytes:7172154 (7.1 MB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
>       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
>
>       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
>
>       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>
>       RX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
>
>       TX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
>
>       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
>
>       RX bytes:8886 (8.8 KB)  TX bytes:8886 (8.8 KB)
> ```

And some logs :

vim /var/log/kern.log

```
 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [    4.438320] EXT4-fs (sda1): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [    4.438327] EXT4-fs (sda1): write access will be enabled during recovery

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.096040] EXT4-fs (sda1): orphan cleanup on readonly fs

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.096040] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7340040

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.096040] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7340039

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.096040] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7340038

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.096040] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7340037

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.096040] EXT4-fs (sda1): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 7340036

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.096040] EXT4-fs (sda1): 5 orphan inodes deleted

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.096040] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   12.190173] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   36.468053] Adding 5448696k swap on /dev/hda5.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:5448696k

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   36.577612] udev: starting version 151

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   36.869644] piix4_smbus 0000:00:07.3: SMBus base address uninitialized - upgrade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.029617] VMBUS_DRV: generating uevent - VMBUS_DEVICE_CLASS_GUID={c5295816-f63a-4d5f-8d1a4daf999ca185}

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.029645] VMBUS_DRV: generating uevent - VMBUS_DEVICE_CLASS_GUID={32412632-86cb-44a2-9b5c50d1417354f5}

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.029751] VMBUS_DRV: generating uevent - VMBUS_DEVICE_CLASS_GUID={cfa8b69e-5b4a-4cc0-b98b8ba1a1f3f95a}

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.029778] VMBUS_DRV: generating uevent - VMBUS_DEVICE_CLASS_GUID={ba6163d9-04a1-4d29-b60572e2ffb1dc7f}

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.029843] VMBUS_DRV: generating uevent - VMBUS_DEVICE_CLASS_GUID={f8615163-df3e-46c5-913ff2d2f965ed0e}

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.323305] lp: driver loaded but no devices found

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.325365] vga16fb: initializing

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.325370] vga16fb: mapped to 0xc00a0000

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.325433] fb0: VGA16 VGA frame buffer device

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   37.508816] udev: renamed network interface eth0 to eth2

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   39.431272] psmouse serio1: ID: 12 00 64

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   39.975057] trackpoint.c: failed to get extended button data

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   40.876129] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 80x30

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   41.271321] type=1505 audit(1407910454.512:2):  operation="profile_load" pid=533 name="/sbin/dhclient3"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   41.273609] type=1505 audit(1407910454.516:3):  operation="profile_replace" pid=516 name="/sbin/dhclient3"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   41.274548] type=1505 audit(1407910454.516:4):  operation="profile_load" pid=516 name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   41.275072] type=1505 audit(1407910454.516:5):  operation="profile_load" pid=516 name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   42.203697] type=1505 audit(1407910455.447:6):  operation="profile_replace" pid=533 name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   42.204264] type=1505 audit(1407910455.448:7):  operation="profile_replace" pid=533 name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   43.175228] type=1505 audit(1407910456.416:8):  operation="profile_load" pid=627 name="/usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   43.194934] type=1505 audit(1407910456.436:9):  operation="profile_replace" pid=629 name="/sbin/dhclient3"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   43.195875] type=1505 audit(1407910456.436:10):  operation="profile_replace" pid=629 name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action"

 Aug 13 02:14:16 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   43.242447] type=1505 audit(1407910456.484:11):  operation="profile_replace" pid=629 name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script"

 Aug 13 02:14:18 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   45.288537] IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x01, buttons: 0/0

 Aug 13 02:14:18 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   45.289856] input: TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3

 Aug 13 02:14:19 hpjs-desktop kernel: [   46.344868] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
```

Update :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the output of `$ dmesg > dmesg.txt` when networking is down. Paste the output on paste.ubuntu.com. Also, please share the network management between the VM and the host and can you SSH the host when the VM is down.

Comment: Since you're hosting, I am assuming bridged mode, but try NAT with port forwarding as well (http://www.virten.net/2013/03/how-to-setup-port-forwarding-in-vmware-workstation-9/).

Comment: Are you using High performance Java sockets (HPJS)?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, so I'll answer here.

Isn't the line `udev: renamed network interface eth0 to eth2` the problem in your log ? see http://blog.giuseppeurso.net/udev-renamed-network-interface-eth-to-eth/ or http://tadek.pietraszek.org/blog/2008/03/04/wth-eth0-got-renamed-to-eth2-after-an-upgrade/ for some examples of resolution.

Comment: Thanks , i commented the lines in that file and will see if it works tomorrow .

Comment: Didnt work ... in fact i can't even connect from the Hyper-v It says connected but just get a black screen and can't do anything not even ssh it .